# Removing gaps between HTML rows in android Gmail and Yahoo clients

Tags: android, html, css, outlook

I am building a simple signature from 4 sliced images. One big header image with spans 3 smaller side by side images in the next row.

When I view the signature in Outlook 2013/2016 it views fine, but when it is received/viewed on Android Gmail or Yahoo client on PC from Outlook there is a gap between the table rows.

When view on Gmail on PC, Thunderbird or Outlook it show prefect.

Spent now days reading suggestions and trying all different options and combinations, and cannot get this correct. I just do not know why Yahoo and Andriod Gmail client puts in a gap between the table rows.

A little further insite as to how I solve this would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Signature</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type"text/css" media="screen">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-size:1px; line-height:0; mso-margin-top-alt:0px;">
    <tr style="display: block; white-space: nowrap;">
        <td style="border-collapse: mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; collapse; line-height: 0; display: inline-block;"><img height="100" src="https://s20.postimg.org/432rtyob1/image.png" width="600" alt="Example Image" style="display: block; border=0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width:600px;">
        <tr style="display: block; white-space: nowrap;">
            <td width="253" height="30" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#"><img height="30" src="https://s20.postimg.org/ru25c2gsd/image.png" alt="" width="253" style="display: block;" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td width="107" height="30" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#"><img height="30" src="https://s20.postimg.org/za1exvjx9/prof.png" alt="" width="107" style="display: block;" border="0"/></a></td>
            <td width="240" height="30" style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#"><img height="30" src="https://s20.postimg.org/za1exvrn1/web.png" alt="" width="240" style="display: block;" border="0" /></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to minify your code before sending it.

Comment: can you add a fiddle of your code?

Comment: The Fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/bigears/8vy2eyne/